# Simplify sum of combinations with same n, all possible values of k

Tags: combinatorics

Is there a way to simplify this equation?

$$\dbinom{8}{1} + \dbinom{8}{2} + \dbinom{8}{3} + \dbinom{8}{4} + \dbinom{8}{5} + \dbinom{8}{6} + \dbinom{8}{7} + \dbinom{8}{8}$$

Or more generally,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dbinom{n}{k}$$

Comment: An ice-cream store manufactures unflavored ice-cream and then adds in _one or more_ of 5 flavor concentrates (vanilla, chocolate, fudge, mint, jamoca) to create the various ice-creams available for sale in the store. So the number of different flavors is $\sum_{k=1}^5 \binom{5}{k}$. Try calculating the number of flavors by hand. For extra credit, identify the store.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations_for_all_k

which says

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$

You can prove this using the binomial theorem where $x=y=1$.

Now, since $\binom{n}{0} = 1$ for any $n$, it follows that

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n - 1$$

In your case $n=8$, so the answer is $2^8 - 1 = 255$.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to figure out all the possible sets  of input features for a regression, so my mind start with statistics but I suppose this question is not stats per se.

Comment: An easy way to see this is : you will take each element (1), or not (0). So you can represent all binary number with n bits : 2^n. And this amounts to all combination with one item removed, plus all combinations with 2 items removed,and so on.. = sum of C(k/N).

Answer (score 17):

Homework?

Hint:

Remember the binomial theorem:

$$

(x+y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}

$$

Now, if you could just find x and y so that $x^ky^{n-k}$ is constant...